# Extract Logs from remoteJobTrigger

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using the below code to trigger a remote job in a a jenkins pipeline. After the job is trigger, I'd need to parse the logs and retrieve few information. The below code used  handle.lastLog() function, but its returning null. Is there a way to get the logs from triggerRemoteJob ?

```
            def handle = triggerRemoteJob (
                auth: TokenAuth(apiToken:....'),...,
                
                job: build_job, 
                parameters: parameters1,
                useCrumbCache: true, 
                useJobInfoCache: true,
                overrideTrustAllCertificates: false,
                trustAllCertificates: true
            )       
            def status = handle.getBuildStatus()
            echo "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
            echo "Log: " + handle.lastLog()
            echo "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many ways to parse the remote job console log by saving the output to a file as follows:

One way is to use the `handle` object to get the remote build URL:

```
def remoteBuildOutput = handle.getBuildUrl().toString()+"consoleText"
sh "curl -o remote_build_output.txt ${remoteBuildOutput} && cat remote_build_output.txt"
```

Another way is to output the last build log:

```
sh "curl -o remote_last_build_output.txt ${env.JENKINS_URL}/job/build_job/lastBuild/consoleText && cat remote_last_build_output.txt"
```

You can use `env.JENKINS_URL` if it's set. If not, you can replace it by your Jenkins URL.

`build_job` is the name of your remote job.

Note that if you're using the `/lastBuild/` api call, you can't garantee that the last build is the same build that was triggered by your job (if the build_job is triggered by another system/person at the same time)

One last way is to enable the [Parameterized Remote Trigger Plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/Parameterized-Remote-Trigger/) logging via the `enhancedLogging` option.

If set to `true`, the console output of the remote job is also logged.

```
def handle = triggerRemoteJob (
            job: build_job, 
            enhancedLogging: true
            ... 
            )
```

You can then save the current job output in a file and parse what ever you want:

```
sh "curl -o current_build_output.txt ${env.JENKINS_URL}job/${env.JOB_NAME}/${currentBuild.number}/consoleText && cat current_build_output.txt"
```

`${currentBuild.number}` can also be replaced by the `${env.BUILD_NUMBER}` variable

Comment: Thanks @YellowStrawHatter . The solution to get the URL through def remoteBuildOutput = handle.getBuildUrl().toString()+"consoleText" gets be the URL. However I'm getting 403 authentication failure when trying to do a GetMethod on this URL. For the triggerRemoteJob  I'm using an TokenAuth() to authenticate. Is ther a way to authenticate  to the remote Jenkins server through the same TokenAuth ?

Comment: I could use the following sh command to get an authentication. curl_cmd =  "curl -L --user ${user_name}:${api_token} -o remote_build_output.txt ${remoteBuildOutputURL} && cat remote_build_output.txt" . The ${user_name}:${api_token}  are exactly the same as the ones used in the TokenAuth()

Comment: Glad it works for you